# C# Getting methods with attribute in abstract class

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, custom-attributes

I'm trying to get methods from which have a specific `Callback` attribute inside the constructor of an abstract class. The challenge here is that I also want the methods from the concrete class which have this attribute.

My abstract class:

```
public abstract class BaseScript
{
    protected readonly CallbacksDictionary Callbacks;

    protected BaseScript(CallbacksDictionary callbacks)
    {
        // Get all methods with the [Callback] attribute including the concrete instance
        var methodsWithCallbackAttr = // ?
    }
}
```

```
public class SomeScript : BaseScript {
    public SomeScript(CallbacksDictionary callbacks) : base(callbacks) { }

    [Callback("transaction")]
    internal Task<bool> Transaction(int amount) {
       // I need to get this method
    }

    internal Task<bool> GetBalance(int accountId) {
         // But not this method
    }
}
```

In the example above I want `methodsWithCallbackAttr` to be a list containing the `Transaction` method if the concrete instance is `SomeScript` i.e. I don't want all the methods from all the classes that inherit from `BaseScript` and have the `Callback` attribute.

I've tried the following. Which **does not work**. This only returns the methods from `BaseScript` which have the `Callback` attribute, but not the methods from `SomeScript`.

```
var callbackMethods = GetType().GetMethods()
    .Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CallbackAttribute), true).Length > 0);
```

Comment: `GetType().GetMethods()` <-- This won't work because that specific `GetMethods()` overload will only return `public` members, but those methods are `internal`. You need to specify `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Dai mentioned in their comment. I needed to specify some additional binding flags because the methods I was looking for are internal and instance specific. The code now looks as follows:

```
var callbackMethods = GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CallbackAttribute), true).Length > 0);
```